# Need the tab space intendation back. Not need of 4 space and warnings

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

When I am using pycharm, suddenly I got one yellow banner (pop up) of 4 space intention, Mistakenly I pressed ok for 4 space indentations. Now tab spaces are accepting but throwing a warning or some times errors. I want back my default indention with tab space and it should not throw a warning. I want a green tick in my code. Even though I changed the intentions settings as mentioned in other StackOverflow answers. Is pycharm has any restore settings?

Comment: notepad++ is quite capable of replacing `'    '` by `'\t'` - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ prefers 4 spaces over tabs - but thats a holy crusade I wont fight... I am not sure if asking for pycharm settings is a fit for StackOverflow ... do they have a help forum? try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to File => Settings => Editor => Code Style => Python => Tab and Indents, check "Use tab character", and hit OK. After that, use Code => Reformat Code, so that your code would be reformatted with tab indentations instead of spaces, and that there will be no more warnings for using tabs as indentation.